# Pass success_url to the activate

Tags: python, django, django-registration

Docs say :

```
 ``success_url``
    The name of a URL pattern to redirect to on successful
    acivation. This is optional; if not specified, this will be
    obtained by calling the backend's
    ``post_activation_redirect()`` method.
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in your `urls.py`, e.g.:

```
url(r'^account/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$', 'registration.views.activate', {'success_url': 'registration_activation_complete'}, name='registration_activate'),
url(r'^account/activate/success/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'registration/activation_complete.html', name='registration_activation_complete'),
```

The other approach is to create your own backend (which is simpler than it sounds) by inheriting from the default backend:

```
from registration.backends.default import DefaultBackend

class MyRegistrationBackend(DefaultBackend):
    def post_activation_redirect(self, request, user):
        # return your URL here
```

The easiest solution is to just name your URL pattern that django-registration should use `registration_activation_complete`. See [Naming URL patterns](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) in the Django docs.